# Ubuntu: одновременно проигрывать разную музыку по bluetooth и проводным наушникам

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, bluetooth

Я слушаю музыку из браузера через наушники. Теперь хочу купить bluetooth адаптер, включить проигрыватель типа Rhythmbox и вывести звук на внешнюю аудиколонку. Причем мне нужно как-то разделить звук - отдельно на наушники, отдельно на колонку. Как это можно сделать, и можно ли вообще?

Система Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/609292/different-applications-different-sound-output-devices